# UK transit visa change of airport

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, biometric-passports

I am traveling back to Ireland from India next month. My flight arrives at London Heathrow and next flight is in next 5 hrs from London Gatwick on the same day. I have valid Irish biometric visa marked BC on it. I am not sure whether I need to apply or not. Can someone please help me to conclude this . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter whether you change Airports. [An Irish BC visa lets you enter the UK to transit on the way to Ireland by air.](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/republic_of_ireland).

So you do **not** Need a UK visa

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention. I have student visa marked BC on it.

Comment: I think the answer means you do not need an _additional_ visa.

Comment: @SeetharamanVenugopal Doesn't matter